# Uncaught (in promise) Error: When called with an action of type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Not sure what I am missing... The request is okay and I can see the data when I console.log in the action creator but for some reason the reducer does not work properly.

Here is the code:

Action:

```
import jsonPlaceholder from "../apis/jsonPlaceholder";

export const fetchPosts = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get("/posts");

    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_POSTS", payload: response.data });
  };
};
```

////

jsonPlaceHolder.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});
```

////

Reducers:
fetchData.js

```
const fetchData = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_POSTS":
      return action.payloads;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default fetchData;
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import fetchData from "./fetchData";

export default combineReducers({
  post: fetchData,
});
```

///

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return { posts: state };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(PostList);
```

The error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: When called with an action of type
> "FETCH_POSTS", the slice reducer for key "post" returned undefined. To
> ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If
> you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of
> undefined.

Comment: It should be `action.payload` not `payloads` in `fetchData.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fetchData = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_POSTS":
      return action.payload; //fixed
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default fetchData;
```